# Typecasting a custom column in rails ActiveRecord?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, types

Let's say we do:

```
default_scope :select => '*, 1+1 AS woah'
```

in a model, we can then access woah as a method on the model, but it's a string. How do we typecast this so that it's an integer?

In my real-world example I'm actually selecting an id from a joined table but it's being typed as a string. I need it to be a ruby integer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

How about using a read-only virtual attribute in your model:

```
default_scope :select => '*. 1+1 AS raw_woah'

def woah
  raw_woah.to_i
end
```